# Issue installing matplotlib with Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pip

I have recently installed Python 3.6 on my Windows 10 machine, due to an error of not being able to install Matplotlib without Python 3.6 or above.

However, when I run `python --version`, it still reports back

> Python 3.5.0

Yet, I can see the Python 3.6 in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.6.

Running `python -m pip install matplotlib` still yields me:

> ```
> ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
> ERROR:
> Beginning with Matplotlib 3.1, Python 3.6 or above is required.
>
> This may be due to an out of date pip.
>
> Make sure you have pip >= 9.0.1.
>
> ----------------------------------------
> ```

I have also tried `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`, but it is already up to date (19.1.1)

I tried directly running Python 3.6 using `python-3.6 -m pip install matplotlib` but got:

> 'python-3.6' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Any assistance is appreciated. I need to install matplotlib by using Python 3.6, and would prefer for 3.6 to be my default instantiation of Python.

Comment: try with python3.6, removing the hyphen, also make sure the new python is on the PATH

Comment: Consider using virtual environment like `venv`, `pipenv` or `conda`. You'll avoid ambiguity when running different versions of Python on your machine.

Comment: Same thing @stradivari, `python3.6 is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. How do I check its on PATH

Comment: I will try to read up on those things @michcio1234

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path, tell me if you don't understand something, you will need the instalation folder, the path in the OP looks like a shortcut

Comment: It's there; same problem @stradivari

Comment: could you paste your PATH here? You want the new python instalation to be before the old one

Comment: if you want to install it (not a good way) then go to your `python.exe` folder then in terminal run command `python.exe -m pip install matplotlib`